# Is it impossible to apply view in authentication method?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, jwt, django-rest-framework-simplejwt

I am trying to refresh jwt token during authentication method.

(Because I want to handle tokens in server-side)

I'm using Django, DRF.

This is my **authentication.py**, which is included in 'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES'

```
class CustomAuthentication(JWTAuthentication):
    def authenticate(self, request):
        header = self.get_header(request)
        if header is None:
            raw_token = request.COOKIES.get(settings.SIMPLE_JWT['AUTH_COOKIE']) or None
        else:
            raw_token = self.get_raw_token(header)
        if raw_token is None:
            # I want to apply CookieTokenRefreshView here
            # But if I apply view, it raises errors

        validated_token = self.get_validated_token(raw_token)
        enforce_csrf(request)
        return self.get_user(validated_token), validated_token
```

When I try to apply CookieTokenRefreshView, (I overrided TokenRefreshView to set jwt as cookie)
error raises. (Actually, error raises already when I just import view)

**Errors**

> ImportError: Could not import 'account.authenticate.CustomAuthentication' for API setting 'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES'.

> ImportError: cannot import name 'APIView' from partially initialized module 'rest_framework.views' (most likely due to a circular import) (\venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py).

Is it impossible to issue access token when access token expires in Django?
Please let me know if there is another solution.

Comment: The ImportError is due to too early import of View. Where is import your CustomAuthentication class ?

Comment: A simple solution is probably to import CookieTokenRefreshView directly at beginning of authenticate function instead of import at top of file. But i do not think it is a good idea, i do not understand why you want to call the RefreshView here instead of using directly function for refrshing token... ?

Comment: my file directory goes like this
account
   - views.py
   - authenticate.py
   - ...

Comment: @LucasGrugru Thank you for your comments. I wanted to call RefreshView because I override the view to set tokens as HttpOnly Cookie. I'd rather find a better way.

Comment: You can't call a view directly. You have to load the corresponding token and extend its life rather I think. the token lib you are using probably already has a method to do this